# MySQL, conditionally adding columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, the first holds data about patients, it looks like this.

```
id       patient       sex         impact
------------------------------------------
1        Bill Jones    male        .1     
2        Sarah Smith   female      .4
```

The second holds "multipliers". These multipliers will be used to multiply the impact in the table above.

```
id       type        type_value     multiplier
-----------------------------------------------
1        patient     Bill Jones     .5
2        sex         male           .3
3        sex         male           .8
4        sex         female         .7
```

I am trying to run a query that will return the following:

```
patient        patient_total        sex_total       new_impact
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bill Jones      .5                   1.1             .16
Sarah Smith      0                   .7              .28
```

Where the new impact is the `(patient_total + sex_total) * impact` for each patient.

Here are the create statements:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `impact`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `impact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `impact` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `impact`
--

INSERT INTO `impact` (`id`, `patient`, `sex`, `impact`) VALUES
(1, 'Bill Jones', 'male', 0.1),
(2, 'Sarah Smith', 'female', 0.4);


--
-- Table structure for table `multipliers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `multipliers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `type_value` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `multiplier` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `multipliers`
--

INSERT INTO `multipliers` (`id`, `type`, `type_value`, `multiplier`) VALUES
(1, 'patient', 'Bill Jones', 0.5),
(2, 'sex', 'male', 0.3),
(3, 'sex', 'male', 0.8),
(13, 'sex', 'female', 0.7);
```

I have tried several iterations of the following query, but can't get it to work :/

**Updated quer - working for sex_total column, not for patient_total column :/**

```
select p.patient, ifnull(sum(ipatient.multiplier), 0) as patient_total, ifnull(sum(isex.multiplier), 0) as sex_total, (ifnull(sum(ipatient.multiplier), 0) + ifnull(sum(isex.multiplier), 0) * p.impact) as new_impact
from impact p 
left outer join multipliers ipatient
on ipatient.type = 'patient' and ipatient.type_value = p.patient 
left outer join multipliers isex
on isex.type = 'sex' and isex.type_value = p.sex 
group by p.patient
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to join in the impact rows and then aggregate the results.  The following does two joins, one for each type of impact:

```
select p.patient, sum(ipatient.multiplier) as patient_total,
       sum(isex.multiplier) as sex_total,
       (sum(ipatient.multiplier) * sum(isex.multiplier) * p.imact
       ) as new_impact
from impact p left outer join
     multipliers ipatient
     on ipatient.type = 'patient' and ipatient.type_value = p.patient left outer join
     multipliers isex
     on isex.type = 'sex' and isex.type_value = p.sex 
group by p.patient;
```

You might need a `coalesce()` if there might be some rows that have no matches for either the patient name or sex.

EDIT:

Dumb. Dumb. Dumb.  The above fails because the `isex` multiplies the rows, so it affects the `sum()` of ipatient.  This version works:

```
select p.patient,
       sum(case when m.type = 'patient' then m.multiplier else 0 end) as patient_total,
       sum(case when m.type = 'sex' then m.multiplier else 0 end) as sex_total,
       (sum(m.multiplier)* p.impact
       ) as new_impact
from impact p left outer join
     multipliers m
     on m.type = 'patient' and m.type_value = p.patient or
        m.type = 'sex' and m.type_value = p.sex 
group by p.patient;
```

You can see it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e008e7/6).

If you don't like all the decimal places from the `float`, you can switch to a numeric/decimal data type.

Comment: It's partially working (with the sex column, not the patient column). I've modified your SQL to work with my create statements. Can you please tell me why the following query isn't working for the patient column? EDIT: I have added the new query to the bottom of my question since it's too long to fit here

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the columns you need, but you'll have to do the multiplication yourself.

```
SELECT i.id, i.patient, i.impact,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(multiplier), 0) FROM multipliers 
       WHERE type='patient' AND type_value=i.patient) `patient_total`,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(multiplier), 0) FROM multipliers 
       WHERE type='sex' AND type_value=i.sex) `sex_total`
FROM impact i
```